# Is reality really epistemological in its complete sense?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, superposition, schroedingers-cat

Taking the case of Schrodinger's cat, if the measurement of the cat is not yet done, then I don't know whether the cat is dead or alive. Epistemologically speaking, since I don't know about the condition of the cat, it is in a superposition state of both dead and alive. But if my friend opens the box and measures it without my knowledge, then for me the cat is still in a superposition state. If QM is epistemological in its complete sense then the collapse of the wave-function is relative.
For him, the cat could be dead and for me, it could have a finite probability of being alive. If my knowledge was the only factor that determines whether the state is in superposition or not (epistemology), then there would be a finite probability that I opened the box and found the cat alive and removed it from the box and go and meet him!. Einstein too said (in the context of relativity) that reality is relative but here(QM) it takes an entirely new meaning.

And what if I forgot that I have measured? There would be a finite probability that I measured it to be dead and then forgot and then again measured it only to find that it was alive!

> Is QM completely epistemological? 
>     If yes then is the forgetting argument valid?

Both of them make no sense to me, but reality need not make sense to me.

Comment: You are going to have to be more descriptive with your question. Its too hard to intemperate as its currently written.

Comment: In the title, you ask about reality.  In the question body, you ask about quantum mechanics.  Which do you mean?  To be clear, quantum mechanics is definitely not a complete theory of reality, being why the distinction matters.

Comment: Not a gist of what an answer to this particular question should look like, but, in general, reality is under no obligation to make sense to you (I mean to anyone, of course). ;-)

Comment: Also, in Relativity, it is extremely clear that reality is not relative--there is an objective reality (described in the language of geometric or covariant objects). The same can be said even in the context of Quantum Mechanics if the Many-Worlds formulation is true (which we cannot say with full certainty as of now because there are unresolved issues with obtaining the Born rule in a Many-Worlds set-up).

Comment: The standard label for this kind of thought experiment is [Wigner's friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend).

Answer (score 3):

First off, we have to define "reality."  It's a fuzzy word.  You appear to be specifically using the Copenhagen Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics.  It's a popular "reality," but not the only one.

The cat is not in a superposition of states because you do not know the condition of the cat.  By the Copenhagen Interpretation (CI), the cat is in a superposition of states because it has not been observed.  This is a small by crucial detail.

Thus, if you *know* the cat has not been observed, you *know* that it is in a superposition of states.

If your friend (assumed to be a classical entity) observes the cat, measuring it, the waveform collapses (according to CI).  At this point the cat is alive or dead, but is not in a superposition of states.

At this point we can address an assumption you made.  You stated "...for me the cat is still in superposition state." This is not true.  For it to be true, it means you know that nobody observed it.  But in this hypothetical situation, your friend *has* observed it, so you do not know that it is in a superposition of states.  If you know your friend observed it, then you know the cat is either alive or dead.  If you do not know whether your friend observed it, you do not know whether the cat is alive, dead, or in a superposition of states.

If you forget your measurement, the same rules apply.  If you forgot the measurement, then the cat has still been observed -- it is either alive or dead, you just don't know which.  If you forget whether a measurement has taken place, then you cannot know whether the cat is alive, dead, or in a superposition of states.

There are other interpretations with different rule.  The Many Worlds Interpretation, in particular, considers a non-real solution, where the question "is the cat alive or dead" depends on the subject observing it, and the subject is "split" into multiple worlds to capture the probabilities associated with quantum mechanics.

That all being said, if you dig deep into the philosophy of science, you find that you cannot *truly* know anything about reality without making assumptions first.  But that's another topic entirely.

Comment: That is a good argument but what if I know that he didn't measure and he actually measured. That is what I mean by being completely based on epistemology.  As per your answer, the wave function collapses  not after me knowing but after somebody measuring. Then that is not completely epistemological .

Comment: @SaiBaikampadi If you know he didn't measure, and he actually measured, then your knowledge is inconsistent with reality, and is not applicable.  By the most traditional definition of "knowledge," knowledge has to be true.  I'm not entirely confident I agree with your use of the term "epistemological," but for what you mean by the word the answer is simple: "No.  No scientific theory has ever suggested reality is epistemological, the way you are using it."  Scientific theories have constantly assumed we can learn knowledge about reality, as opposed to our knowledge shaping reality.

Comment: _"If you do not know whether your friend observed it, you do not know whether the cat is alive, dead, or in a superposition of states."_ Yes, if the focus is about "knowing" then this is correct and a fantastically clear description. But, it might be noticed that if you really haven't measured your friend (friendship?) then your friend is in a superposition of having measured the cat and of not having measured the cat with respect to you. And, in that case, it is not just that you don't know but it really is a superposition.

Comment: Furthermore, even if you do know that your friend has measured the cat (via measuring your friend with an operator that has two distinct eigenvalues corresponding to him having measured the cat and not having measured the cat), you still cannot say that the cat is actually either alive or dead. Because, the eigenspace of your friend having measured the cat is a superposition of him having measured it alive and the cat being alive and of him having measured it dead and the cat being dad.

Comment: @DvijMankad For this, I assumed the Copenhagen Interpreation, which seemed as close to what the OP was looking for as I could manage.  It is a theory for explaining how a classical being could consistently measure the results of a quantum system.  I thus assumed that the friend is also a classical being (as they would want to be treated the same as I).  If I were to treat the friend as an entity controlled by quantum laws, then I would have to be very precise in how I capture the idea of the friend measuring the cat, as I could no longer use the CI concept of collapsing a waveform to do it.

Comment: Decoherence theories do a better job of capturing that nuance than the traditional CI interpretation.  They capture the concept of measurement as an interaction between a particle and particles in decoherent states that are modeled statistically.  They do a good job of capturing the nuances of having a friend "observe" the cat.  This detail became a big deal a while back when someone constructed a thought experiment which, by naive approaches, suggested that a coin was heads *or* tails, depending on the observer.  The trick was in mishandling the idea of a friend measuring.

Comment: "That all being said, if you dig deep into the philosophy of science, you find that you cannot truly know anything about reality without making assumptions first. But that's another topic entirely." - Or, perhaps, that quantum theory is in a sense _thrusting this forward into our face_ , instead of leaving it buried down "deep" in philosophic argument.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I think QM has been dredging up this issue, though we seem to be pretty good at bringing it back to truths, even if they are just statistical truths like are claimed in the Bell inequalities.  Since writing this, I've actually been given the terms for what I was grasping at here.  There's the usual attitude of scientific realism, which is that the things science describe *are*.  Then there's insturmentalism, which suggests the things science describe are just models that appear to predict things well, which is a whole lot less popular.  Lots of fun learning new terms!

Answer (score 3):

Your particular example of the Schrodinger cat is unfortunate. In physics there are various frameworks where mathematical models describe "reality" .That means that the models are successful in describing and , **important**, **predicting situations**, as you are trying to do. The different frameworks can be shown mathematically to emerge from lower levels, i.e. classical mechanics which is the framework of you and your friend and the cat, emerges from quantum mechanics  BUT in  a mathematically complicated manner. Superposition of states can happen only in the framework of quantum mechanics by superposition of wavefunctions, in dimensions commensurate within the quantum uncertainty of $Δ(x)Δ(p)>h/{2π}$.

Paradoxes arise from mixing frameworks and the laws of frameworks. Quantum mechanics  measures probabilities to be validated. Classical mechanics measures positions by rulers and energies by specially  made instrumentation. The detectors  used to measure the quantum mechanical probabilities obey the rules of classical theories, measuring energy and momenta (cat has different energy alive or dead, a classical object) etc and fitting distributions with quantum mechanical theory.

The cat in the Schrodinger box is a detector. A single probabilistic quantum mechanical decay of the nucleus  will trigger the poison that will kill the cat. What is unknown is **when the nucleus will decay** , that is given by a quantum mechanical probability distribution, i.e. the wavefunction of the particle decaying complex conjugate square, as far as quantum theory goes. Thus the specific nucleus is in a state where it may or may not decay, with a given probability. If nobody detects it, its state will not be known. If the cat in the box detector detects it , it means there was a decay, i.e. a measurement in the probability distribution of the nucleus decay.

Thus you are getting a paradox because you ( and Schrodinger) are mixing two frameworks, the probabilistic of the underlying quantum mechanical decay, with the cat/poison as a detector.